# How to append new attributes in xml using Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have xml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
  <Platform>
    <D1>8536</D1>
  </Platform>
  <Timestamp>
    <Create>Friday, August 23, 2019 4:34:18 PM</Create>
  </Timestamp>
</DATA>
```

I want to add an element in `<Timestamp>`.
My Expectation like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
  <Platform>
    <D1>8536</D1>
  </Platform>
  <Timestamp>
    <Create>Friday, August 23, 2019 4:34:18 PM</Create>
    <Info>Started</Info>
  </Timestamp>
</DATA>
```

Here's my attempt so far:

```
$fileName = "D:\file.xml"
$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName)
$newXmlEmployeeElement = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Info")
$newXmlEmployee = $xmlDoc.DATA.Timestamp.AppendChild($newXmlEmployeeElement)
$xmlDoc.Save($fileName)
```

Anyone can help really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can't append to XML at the end.  The XML specification defines a "Well-Formed" XML document to have only one element at the root (not an array).  So adding to the end of a document makes the XML not "Well Formed".  Many applications (like XML LOG files) do create arrays, but not all xml tools can use the array format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing missing from your code is to create the content for your new `<Info>` element:

```
$newXmlEmployeeElement.InnerText = 'Started'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `InnerText` property of the newly created element:

```
$fileName = "test.xml"
$xmlDoc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content $fileName)
$newXmlEmployeeElement = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("Info")
$newXmlEmployee = $xmlDoc.DATA.Timestamp.AppendChild($newXmlEmployeeElement)

# Set the value via this line!
$newXmlEmployeeElement.InnerText = "1.2.3.4"


$xmlDoc.Save($fileName)
```

Getting the content of the file:

```
> gc .\test.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
  <Platform>
    <D1>8536</D1>
  </Platform>
  <Timestamp>
    <Create>Friday, August 23, 2019 4:34:18 PM</Create>
    <Info>1.2.3.4</Info>
  </Timestamp>
</DATA>
```